# How to write literal \n in a file as text from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash

I write this in terminal:

```
printf ' \n\necho -e \"writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text'\n'on 2lines (with "-e" and "'\n'" help)\" >> note.txt\n' > note.txt
```

I get this in `note.txt`:

```
echo -e "writes (>> appends) in note.txt this textnon 2lines (with "-e" and "n" help)" >> note.txt
```

I want to get this in `note.txt`:

```
echo -e "writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text\non 2lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)" >> note.txt
```

(`\`- is missing)

Comment: See here.http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Answer (score 8):

#### Way 1: Escape instances of `\` that you don't want to escape other characters.

Based on the contents of your string, you probably want:

```bsh
echo -e 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text\non 2 lines (with "-e" and "\\n" help)' >> note.txt
```

The text this appends to `note.txt` is:

```
writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text
on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)
```

The changes are:

- You had `/n` where it looked like you wanted a line break. So I changed that to `\n`.
- In the text `with "-e" and "\n"`, the `\` is intended to be printed literally rather than to combine with the `n` following it and produce a newline. So I quoted (escaped) `\` with another `\`. If `\n` produces a new line, `\\n` produces `\n`.
- I replaced the outer double quotes (`"`) with single quotes (`'`). You wanted the `"` characters around `-e` and `\n` to be printed literally, but instead they ended and restarted quoting, preventing them from being printed and causing `\n` to actually be printed as `n` (because an unquoted `\n` is processed before being passed to `echo`). An alternative solution would have been to write `\"` for the inside `"` characters. But there was no reason to enclose the whole thing in double quotes--[single quotes are usually preferable in cases where either can be used](https://askubuntu.com/a/526482/22949).

  <sup>The other change--which was not a change in the final command but was a change I made *just while working on it*--was that I removed the `>> note.txt` redirection until I knew I had the command right. By sending output to the terminal, I was immediately able to see what the effect was. I re-added the redirection when I was done.</sup>

That's stylistically closest to what you already had, but it's not the only way to do it.

#### Way 2: Separate `echo` commands for separate lines, instead of using `-e`.

Since the only sequence you want treated specially by echo is the `\n` (between `text` and `on`), you can just use two separate `echo` commands and (as [muru may be suggesting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533302/write-n-in-a-file-as-text-from-terminal#comment729188_533302)) *not* use `-e`.

Here are two ways of redirecting the output of multiple commands:

1. Two separate redirections, one for each command.

   ```bsh
   echo 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text' >> note.txt
   echo 'on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)' >> note.txt
   ```

   If the filename is long or you're writing a script and only want to have to change it in one place, you can assign it to a variable:

   ```bsh
   out="/home/ek/Documents/long name that can have spaces as it's quoted/note.txt"
   echo 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text' >> "$out"
   echo 'on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)' >> "$out"
   ```
2. A single redirection applied to a compound command composed of the two commands.

   ```bsh
   {
       echo 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text'
       echo 'on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)'
   } >> note.txt
   ```

   You can put that on one line if you like, but if there's no newline before the closing brace (`}`), a semicolon (`;`) must precede it:

   ```bsh
   { echo 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text'; echo 'on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)'; } >> note.txt
   ```

#### Way 3: Pass a literal `\n` to `echo` instead of using `-e`.

Real newlines can appear inside quotes (single or double) and are interpreted literally:

```bsh
echo 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text
on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)' >> note.txt
```

Because the first line ends inside quotes, the shell doesn't take it as the end of the command, but instead continues reading.

If you do want to fit it on a single line, you can use `$'\n'`, which expands to a newline. This is expanded by the shell *before* being passed to the `echo` command, so it should not be quoted.

```
echo 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text'$'\n''on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)' >> note.txt
```

#### Way 4: Use `printf`

`printf` is very powerful; there are a number of ways you could use it to solve this problem. Since I am presenting this as a distinct solution from the others, here's a good way to use it in a way you cannot use `echo`:

```bsh
printf '%s\n%s\n' 'writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text' 'on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)' >> note.txt
```

The general syntax for `printf` is `printf format args...` (where `args...` means zero or more additional command-line arguments). The format string above, `%s\n%s\n`, means:

1. `%s`: consume and print the next unused (i.e., first) argument in `args...` (i.e., your 1st line).
2. `\n`: print a newline.
3. `%s`: consume and print the next unused (i.e., second) argument in  `args...` (i.e., your 2nd line).
4. `\n`: print a newline.

When there are more arguments after the format string than the format string calls for, the `printf` command starts over from the beginning of the format string. Thus, while less self-documenting, you could actually write just `'%s\n'` (instead of `'%s\n%s\n'`) for the format string, and it would produce the same output in this case.

I will not attempt to broadly document `printf` here. Instead, see:

- The output of `help printf`.
- The `printf` subsection of [4.2 Bash Builtin Commands](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) in [the bash reference manual](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).
- [This manual page, documenting the standard printf command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/printf.1posix.html) (which bash slightly extends).
- The `printf()` function in the standard C library, which the `printf` command is based on, and which is referred to explicitly in the above resources. [Documentation on it, such as this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), is both more thorough and more accessible than most sources on the `printf` command. And the format string syntax is very similar.

#### Way 5: Use `cat` and a here document.

This way is especially valuable when there's a lot of input, and when scripting. If you're using the shell interactively rather than writing a script, you can use this, but please consider **Way 6** below first.

While `echo` and `printf` print text based on the contents of their command-line arguments, `cat` prints the contents of its input files (as specified on the command line) or, if given none (or passed `-`), its [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29).

With no redirections, standard input is what you type on a program's controlling terminal. [**Here documents**](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) are a special kind of redirection. Lines are collected until a specified keyword (I've used `EOF`) appears by itself on a line. Then the lines up to but not including `EOF` (or whatever you used) are given as standard input to the command being run.

```bsh
cat >> note.txt << EOF
writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text
on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)
EOF
```

One of the differences between quoting with `"` and `'` is that most expansions and substitutions with `$` (e.g., `$varname`) are performed in double quotes, but none are in single quotes. There are also two ways to use here documents, based on whether `$` (and also `` ` `` and `\`) are to be given special meaning or treated literally.

In this case, it doesn't matter--`$` and `` ` `` don't appear, and `\` is only treated specially in a here document when it escapes a [shell metacharacter](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions) (not `n`). Just as in single and double quoted expressions, both ways treat `\n` literally. (Remember, you had to use a special feature of `echo`, turned on by `-e`, to get `\n` treated specially.)

But so you know for other applications:

- The way shown above will perform expansions and substitutions, treating `$`, `` ` ``, and `\` specially when they appear in a context where their special meaning applies.
- To cause all text to be treated literally, quote all or part of the word appearing to the right of `<<` with `'`, `"`, `\`, or a combination thereof (e.g., `cat >> note.txt << 'EOF'`).

#### Way 6: Use `cat` without any input redirection.

If you're using the shell interactively, by default the shell's [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29) is taken from your terminal. When you then run a program, by default that program's standard input is taken from your terminal too. (This may be changed by input redirections, of course.)

So if you're running a command interactively and want to use `cat` with `>>` or `>` output redirection to send data to a file, you don't need any input redirection. Just enter:

```bsh
cat >> note.txt
writes (>> appends) in note.txt this text
on 2 lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)
^D
```

In place of *`^D`*, don't enter a literal `^D`. Instead, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. That signals to your terminal that it should report *[end of file](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=End-of-file)* (i.e., that when the running program asks for more input, it is told that there is none left, just as if it had reached the end of a regular file stored on disk). When `cat` sees there's no more input, it exits, and you are returned to the shell.

If you're writing a script, Way 6 will not work, because bash reads commands from a file but standard input is still (typically) a something else, such as your terminal.

One notable difference between using `cat` with a here document and using cat with no input redirection, even when standard input is your terminal, is that:

- `cat >> note.txt` writes one line at a time to `note.txt`. Each time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, a line is written to `note.txt`.
- `cat >> note.txt << EOF` takes all input up to the `EOF` line, *then* appends it to `note.txt`. If you interrupt the input by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, nothing is written (and if `note.txt` didn't exist already, it is not even created).

Comment: Ty for your extensiv answer, it is truly great for me, this is what I'm looking for- to find answers to questions I din't know I have. :)

Comment: Answer of the year!  you're a maniac! ;-)

Comment: A great tutorial showing many ways to skin this particular cat.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I hope this satisfies your needs:

1. Press, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type, in the following command:
   `nano`
3. An editor in the terminal would open for you.
4. Type in whatever you want, in your case:
   `echo -e 'writes(>> appends) in note.txt this text/non 2lines (with "-e" and "\n" help)' >> note.txt` (that's what I got from your question)
5. To **Save and Exit**,

   - Press, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
   - Will ask for a confirmation message to **save**, press <kbd>y</kbd>
   - Type, a name for your file, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. To Check,

   - Open **File Manager**, you'll see a file that you saved.
   - You'll, probably find all your text (including, "\n")

Answer (score 1):

The shell interperlates special characters like the backslash, except when it's surrounded by single quotes.

`echo` takes arguments beginning with dash, so to be extra safe, you should use `printf` instead, like this:

```
$ printf %s 'A \n B \n'
A \n B \n
```

`%s` just means print the string I'm passing as an argument. It's often used like this:

```
$ variable=Flimm
$ printf '%s is all right\n' "$variable"
Flimm is all right
```

You can find out more about the Bash's interpolation in the [manpage for the `bash` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash), search for the section entitled QUOTING. Also look at the [manpage for the `printf` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/printf.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

The character `\` is also an escape character for itself, so you can add an additional `\` like so:

```
mgodby@mg-ws1:~$ echo -e '\n'


mgodby@mg-ws1:~$ echo -e '\\n'
\n
mgodby@mg-ws1:~$
```

Comment: dear god it works:D so the solution was to use '' single quotes, and /, I feel stupid now but at least I learned something TYall

Answer (score 0):

one more way:

```
perl -e 'print q{
this preserves \n backslash-n
and other special characters except close-squiggle 
(without a matching open-squiggle, which would be very rare)
}' > note.txt
```

if your note has a close-squiggle you can chose another delimeter to the q() function:

```
perl -e 'print q|

this works even with an unmatched close-squiggle
like this one: }

but it doesnt workt if i have a pipe in my text...

|' > note.txt
```

of course all these methods (perl or native printf) will fail if you have
a single-quote inside your document. in this case you may be able to use
double-quotes (so long as you dont have both single and double inside your text) eg

```
printf %s " I'm an idiot"
```